# How to run unbalanced two factor nested design in R?

Tags: r, unbalanced-classes, nested-data, permutation-test

I am searching for the best way to analyse disease occurrence data knowing that I have an unbalanced nested design. I was thinking on using **nested.npmanova() in BiodiversityR package** but it becomes tricky as my design is unbalanced.

Here some details:
Data are disease occurrence on benthic organisms (continuous response variable not disease counts). Factors are **Exposure** (fixed, two levels: outerreef and lagoon) and **Site** (random and nested in Exposure with three levels for the outerreef and two levels for the lagoon). Four transects were conducted at each site except at one site in the lagoon where there are only three transects.

So my question is: is it possible to use nested.npmanova for this unbalanced nested design? Any help or example on how to use this function would be greatly appreciated.